# Concurrent Akka Agents in Scala

Tags: scala, akka, agent

I'm working on a scala project right now, and I've decided to use Akka's agent library over the actor model, because it allows a more functional approach to concurrency.However, I'm having a problem running many different agents at a time. It seems like I'm capping at only having three or four agents running at once.

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.agent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object AgentTester extends App {
// Create the system for the actors that power the agents
implicit val system = ActorSystem("ActorSystem")

// Create an agent for each int between 1 and 10
val agents = Vector.tabulate[Agent[Int]](10)(x=>Agent[Int](1+x))

// Define a function for each agent to execute
def printRecur(a: Agent[Int])(x: Int): Int = {
    // Print out the stored number and sleep.
    println(x)
    Thread.sleep(250)

    // Recur the agent
    a sendOff printRecur(a) _

    // Keep the agent's value the same
    x
}

// Start each agent
for(a <- agents) {
    Thread.sleep(10)
    a sendOff printRecur(a) _
}
}
```

The above code creates an agent holding each integer between 1 and 10. The loop at the bottom sends the printRecur function to every agent. The output of the program should show the numbers 1 through 10 being printed out every quarter of a second (although not in any order). However, for some reason my output only shows the numbers 1 through 4 being outputted.

Is there a more canonical way to use agents in Akka that will work? I come from a clojure background and have used this pattern successfully there before, so I naively used the same pattern in Scala.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you are running on a 4 core box and that is part of the reason why you only ever see the numbers 1-4.  The big thing at play here is that you are using the default execution context which I'm guessing on your system uses a thread pool with only 4 threads on it (one for each core).  With the way you've coded this in this sort of recursive manner, my guess is that the first 4 agents never relinquish the threads and they are the only ones that will ever print anything.

You can easily fix this by removing this line:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

And adding this line after you create the `ActorSystem`

```
import system.dispatcher
```

This will use the default dispatcher for the actor system which is a fork join dispatcher which does not seem to have the same issue as the default execution context you imported in your sample.

You could also consider using `send` as opposed to `sendOff` as that will use the execution context that was available when you constructed the agent.  I would think one would use `sendOff` when they had a case where they explicitly wanted to use another execution context.

Comment: Using send over sendOff didn't make a difference, but swapping out the imports did. Thanks!